# Parametising xUnit tests with multiple types from F#

Tags: f#, xunit

I want to parametise my tests similar to how I have [done it here](https://github.com/DotNetIO/DotNetIO/blob/master/src/DotNetIO.Tests/copying_files/locked_file.cs), but for xUnit and with F#.

In the linked code, the base class instantiates the file system implementation, letting subclasses to the specialised testing.

I only need to receive instances that are different implementations of the same interface, this time; how do I go about this the best way?

[Here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/09/GenericunittestingwithxUnit.net/) and [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5) are similar resources, but they don't solve the problem in a nice F#-esque way.

Preferrably I would like to use ML functors, but not having that, do I really have to start doing subtyping?

Comment: I'd look into treating tests as first-class values (which xUnit doesn't support AFAIK)

Comment: Do you mean like FsCheck?

Comment: No. Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/mausch/5530144

Answer (score 1):

You can use xUnit theories in xunit.extensions :

```
open System
open System.IO
open Xunit
open Xunit.Extensions


module MyTests =
    [<InlineData(FileShare.None)>]
    [<InlineData(FileShare.Write)>]
    [<InlineData(FileShare.Delete)>]
    let [<Theory>] ``test title`` (fs:FileShare) =
        printfn "fileShare=%s" (fs.ToString())
```